# ASP.NET RadioButtonList help. If I set a selectedItem, that item doesn't react to SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList on my web form. I have tried two different means to set the selected item. I have tried in the markup, and in code, like the Page_Load event. It sets and displays correctly. My problem is that the selected radio button no longer responds to the SelectedIndexChanged event. The other items works as expected and if I remove the code that sets the selectedItem, then the radio button works as expected. Is there any way I can set a radio button through code, and it still behaves as I would expect. I am guessing, if u force a button to be selected, then it doesn't change. Does anyone know how to rememdey this so I can default select it, but still have it behave the way I want?

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPaymentType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem Value="benefit" Text="Benefit" Selected="True"/>
            <asp:ListItem Value="expense" Text="Expense" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This lives inside an ascx which I have an event for

```
  public delegate void SwitchBenefitTypeHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event SwitchBenefitTypeHandler SwitchedBenefit;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WireEvents();
    }


    private void WireEvents()
    {
        rblPaymentType.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => SwitchedBenefit(sender, args);

    }
```

Then on the aspx, I wire a handler function to that event.

```
if (header is PaymentHeader)
                (header as PaymentHeader).SwitchedBenefit += (paymentForm as PaymentBaseControl).Update;
```

Finally the handler function

```
public override void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadioButtonList)
        {
            IsExpense = (sender as RadioButtonList).SelectedValue == "expense";
            UpdateCalcFlag();
            UpdateDropDownDataSources();
            UpdatePaymentTypeDropDown();
            ResetBenefitLabels();
            FormatAmountTextBox();
        }
    }
```

I hope that's enough code. Everything works great when I don't set the SelectedItem in the RadioButtonList but I need it set.

Here's a link to someone with the same problem. It is ASP.NET AJAX related. [Click Here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t589911-radiobuttonlist-selectedindexchanged-not-working-correctly-in-ajax.html)
Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code. Could you post the snippet related to your issue?

Comment: Do you mean that the event fires if you click on any other radio button but even if you click back on the pre-selected one no event fires?

Comment: @Yadyn - yes that is correct.

Comment: I think we're going to need even more code.  I've got a page in a system I'm working on here at work that has almost an identical RadioButtonList.  Flow layout, Horizontal, with two in-markup ListItems, first one selected through markup.  SelectedIndexChanged works fine.  Now, maybe you just left it out of the example, but are you sure you are attaching an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged?  I don't see one in your markup, so are you doing it in the page load or something?

Comment: @Yadyn - yes there is no event handler declared on declarative markup for SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: @all - Yes there is a handler wired up. I have provided the code above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
radiobutton.Items.FindByText("VALUE").Selected = true;
```